# Why does Cookie get lost after page reload?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

This is the code:

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost',
  credentials: true
}));

const token = generateToken(user._id);

const cookieOptions = {
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
  httpOnly: false,
  sameSite: 'none',
  secure: false
}

res.cookie('jwt',token,cookieOptions);
```

And finally in client side:

```js
const res = await axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:80/api/v1/users/login',
  withCredentials: true ,
  data: {
    email,
    password
  }
})

console.log('Response : ', res);
```

I tried to login from -localhost/login route and after every successful login a cookie is being sent to the browser.
But when I try to access this  -localhost/tours route the cookie gets lost

Comment: Can you format your code a bit better in order to read easier ? first you need to specify your localhost: port, on your cors option, you re in local developement and with different port I suppose? And what did you mean the cookie get lost? you mean it "disapear" on your browser or it's more like when you make your request the cookie is not present on the request header ?

Comment: Looks like the cookie is not being saved by the browser. If you are using `Chrome`, you can see a yellow triangle next to the cookie header from response and if you hover on that, you can see why the cookie is not saved.